# How can I send email post on azure website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, azure, smtp

I need to send email letters to notify users about registration and other. How can I do that without azure plugins. I can't use azure plugins because my subscription doesn't let me to install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is an "Azure plugin"?
For my emails I use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient + SendGrid.com

Comment: SendGrid is exactly what I meant, when I said azure plugin.

Comment: If you are sure that I can use it on any azure subscription, tell me how?

Comment: You don't HAVE to add SendGrid to your Azure subscription via the Windows Azure Store.  That just makes things a little easier (authentication, billing, etc. get consolidated).  You can sign up for SendGrid separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send email, you can send emails via the `System.Net` Smtp classes.

If you have a gmail account, you can send mails via Gmail. See this question for an example of the code.

[How to send email to gmail using SMTPclient in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700115/how-to-send-email-to-gmail-using-smtpclient-in-c)

you can also put mail settings into your Web/Worker Roles config file.

[GMail + C# + Web.Config: Send Mail Works Programmatically, Throws Exception Using Web.Config Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391079/gmail-c-sharp-web-config-send-mail-works-programmatically-throws-exception)

Comment: Somehow gmail blocks my account after one letter.