# My ForgotPassword method is not sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my forgot password method that although its status=RantoCompletion but there is no email received at all. I've tried many email addresses and there is nothing. can any one tell me what might be the problem.
here is the code:

```
   // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

and here is my debugging image:
[image: an image of my debugging]

Comment: How do you configure your email settings? What smtp server do you use? For troubleshooting purpose try `UserManager.SendEmail(` instead of the Async version... that way it is easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry I'm just new to asp.net, and I don't know how to know that. can you tell me please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you configure your Web.Config with the proper smtp server settings? Refer to this discussion: [GMail + C# + Web.Config: Send Mail Works Programmatically, Throws Exception Using Web.Config Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391079/gmail-c-sharp-web-config-send-mail-works-programmatically-throws-exception)

What you need to set is this:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="your@emailaddress.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="true" userName="your@emailaddress.com" password="somepassword" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

After that, try changing this line:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

To this:

```
UserManager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

Note the absence of `Async` and `await`, and then try to debug your application, you should be able to see the stacktrace should anything wrong happens.