# ASP.Net C# Sending E-Mail SMTP Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Hello guys I'm trying to send an e-mail from my ASP.Net web application I am using this on my Web.config:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="myemail" password="mypass" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

and it's all correct but I'm getting this error message:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or not done client authentication. 
The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. 
Learn more at at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse 
(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) in System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send 
(SmtpConnection conn, Byte [] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) 
in System.Net. Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail (MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection 
recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, 
SmtpFailedRecipientException & exception) in System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send 
(MailMessage message) at Account_Registration.Registration () 
in c: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2013 \ WebSites \ 
MyWebsite \ Account \ Registration.aspx.cs: line 177
```

As you can see in my Web.config file I have enabled the Ssl so still I get this error and an e-mail to my account that somebody tried to use my e-mail without permission. Anybody can help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391079/gmail-c-sharp-web-config-send-mail-works-programmatically-throws-exception

Answer (score 0):

`<appSettings>
    <add key="EmailHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="EmailPort" value="587" />
    <add key="EmailUsername" value="myemail" />
    <add key="EmailPassword" value="mypass" />`

```
        var mailClient = new SmtpClient(
            Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"]),
            Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPort"]))
        {
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential(
                    Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailUsername"]),
                    Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]))
            //EnableSsl = true
        };

        mailClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) => {
            mailClient.Dispose();
        };
        return mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
```

Comment: Nope, not working I don't even get an error message but thanks for the try :)